# Can anyone tell me if my unit test to this function is correct?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

The FillUpWater function i was to test is as follows?

```
public bool FillUpWater()
{ 
   WaterTap tap = new WaterTap();
    if (tap.FillUpContainer())
    { 
      Level = 5; 
      return true;
    } 
    else
    { 
      return false;
    }
}
public void FillUpWater()
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

my unit test:

```
[TestClass()]
public class WaterContainer
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void WhenWaterContainerIsEmpty_FillingItUp_CausesCorrectWaterLevel()    // Uppgift 4: Vattenbehållaren fylls av 
    {                                                                              // vattenkranen automatisk om den är tom
        // arrange
        WaterContainer waterC = new WaterContainer(0);
        WaterTap tap = new WaterTap();

        // act
        waterC= tap.FillUpContainer();
        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(5, WaterC.Level);
        //Assert.IsTrue(tap.FillUpContainer());
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that it may not be correct? Have you tried to compile and run it? Did it produce an unexpected result? If so, what did you get, and what did you expect? (a hint: neither of your two code samples will compile).

Comment: 1) Decide what exactly you want to validate with a test. 2) Write the test. 3) Make sure the test actually tests what you think it does, i.e. make sure you see it fail, and fail *for the right reasons*. (Ideally write the test *before* you implement / fix a bug. If you do it afterwards, change the implementation locally in order to verify your test.) -- Your question sounds as if you missed step 1...

Comment: Hi Fredrik! I tried to run the test but got som errors, i.e WaterContainer() does not contain a constructor that takes 1 parameter. WaterTap() is inaccesible due to protection level, but when i check , it's neither protected or private. The function above i want to test should fill the container to 5 as soon as the level gets down to -1. how should i go about Writing this test properly? i assume the tap object tap fills the waterContainer object waterC.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few problems here. I have placed each issue in a comment...

```
[TestClass()]
public class WaterContainer
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void WhenWaterContainerIsEmpty_FillingItUp_CausesCorrectWaterLevel() {

        // There seems to be no relationship between the container
        // and the tap - so how will the tap cause any change
        // to the container?
        WaterContainer waterC = new WaterContainer(0);
        WaterTap tap = new WaterTap();

        // The method that you shared with us is called:
        // FillUpWater, but this is calling FillUpContainer
        waterC= tap.FillUpContainer();

        // You create a variable named:
        // waterC, but use WaterC here (C# is case sensitive)
        Assert.AreEqual(5, WaterC.Level);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi steve! as you can see i'm still new in unit testing. what i meant with the above code is that i assumed the tap object of the WaterTap class will fill the waterContainer object waterC as soon as the level gets down to -1. FillUpContainer is a bool method of the WaterTap class, returns true or false. FillUpWater is a method of a WaterContaner class. It's confusing me as well, that's why i need help to understand the correct way to unit test this function.